# What is the bext way to update user profile info in AD from Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

Is there a way to update a users profile in AD from sharepoint?

Is there a web part available, one that I can develop or any other interface that I could build/use?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use the native User Profile Export functionality?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I meant I'd like to present one of our HR staff with an interface/web part (Form hosted on SharePoint) to manage any trivial profile changes such as phone numbers and emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great solution on CodePlex to address my need. It works great on our installation of Sharepoint Server 2010 Enterprise Version with SP1.

Here is the link: http://nominesptools.codeplex.com/